# Conjugacy class in SO(4)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

Is it true that a matrix of the form
$$ R =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta_1 & \sin \theta_1 & 0 & 0\\
-\sin \theta_1 & \cos \theta_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cos \theta_2 & \sin \theta_2\\
0 & 0 & -\sin \theta_2 & \cos \theta_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $\theta_1+\theta_2=0$
is conjugate in SO(4) to a matrix of the form
$$ R' =
\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ is some 3x3 matrix and the 0's are column and row, namely that there exists $h \in SO(4)$ such that
$R'=h^{-1} R h$ ?

Comment: In a word, no..

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown ok, what about this weaker version?

Comment: In another word, no. The original has eigenvalues $\exp(\pm i\theta_1)$. To be similar to $R'$ one (so all) of them must equal $1$.